# Accelerometer Scale parameter

Tags: accelerometer, nucleo

I am using X-NUCLEO-IKS01A3 Shield for my NUCLEO-F401RE platform.

I want to get accelerometer readings so I am using LSM6DSO IMU sensor for that. I tried creating some functions to easily control Scale and ODR parameters, but I spotted quite odd behavior of this sensor.

When I am setting scale to +/- 2G I get a reading of 2 on Z axis, when I set Scale to +/- 4G, I get reading of 1, when I set it to +/- 8 G, I get 0.5. Why is that?

Shouldn't I get 1 on all scales on Z axis ? It is earth gravitational force, which is 1 G, so why am I getting scaled readings?

As I understand, smaller scale  factor let's me get more precise data, larger scale parameter makes it less sensitive, but extends the range.

Comment: Something seems to be wrong with the selection of scales. +/- 4G seems to be +/- 1G, +/- 8G seems  +/- 2G and +/- 1G seems. I would read the datasheet about selecting scale very carefully and check my test program.

Comment: How are you interpreting the data, do you have code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that the project that I am using is not very flexible and is created for 4G scale only. I managed to trace where the value is being read and found this :

```
acc_out->x = (float)data.data.acc_x * 0.122f / 1000.0f;
acc_out->y = (float)data.data.acc_y * 0.122f / 1000.0f;
acc_out->z = (float)data.data.acc_z * 0.122f / 1000.0f;
```

After some investigation on datasheet I came along with this table:
[image]

Then after some reverse calculations I can now say that this was the problem. Since my sensor is using 16 bit for data output, max number is 65536 for selected scale (let's use +/-2G for this explanation), since sensor output is signed number, we get 65536 / 2 =  3278 to represent +2 G, other half is for negative values. Since Earth gravitational force is 1G, I should read 32768 / 2 = 16384 value (32768 is 2G, then 1G is calculated this way), then multiplying it by 0.061 (from the table) and dividing by 1000 gives me: 16384 * 0.061 / 1000 = 0.999 G. Since I changed the Scale and left sensitivity value the same, I got wrongly parsed data.